# What does this sentence mean?

Tags: baseball, terminology, statistics

> The Red Sox got help from star David Ortiz, who went three for four
>   with an RBI double and is now hitting .733 in the Fall Classic.

I have no knowledge about baseball statistics so please help me understand this sentence.

Answer (score 3):

"Three for four" refers to the batter (David Ortiz) reaching base safely by means of a basehit (single, double, triple or homerun) three out of the 4 times he has batted in the game they are referring to.

"an RBI double" refers to Ortiz getting a hit (a double) and reaching second base, which caused another runner to score (an RBI - run batted in)

"is now hitting .733" - refers to his batting average in the World Series games only.

"the Fall Classic" refers to the World Series.

Comment: Not necessarily, and not likely. It just means that the double that he DID hit, drove in a run (RBI). The other hits were likely just singles, or they probably would have mentioned what kind of hits they were. But you would have to look at the box score of the game to know for sure what the 3 hits were.

Comment: [Box Score](http://sports-ak.espn.go.com/mlb/boxscore?gameId=331028124&teams=boston-red-sox-vs-st.-louis-cardinals)